# Which iCloud tasks are done automatically?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, icloud

I use following method to *sync* my files with iCloud.

```
[NSFileManager defaultManager] setUbiquitous:YES itemAtURL:fileURL destinationURL:destURL error:&error
```

I was wondering when I move a file to Ubiquitous Container How would it behave in another device?

will it be **downloaded** automatically?
what about **deleting** and **editing** files?
Does iCloud do above tasks itself or I should handle them manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it would be downloaded automatically 
But I still wonder about deleting and edidting

Comment: It seems the deleting is automatic too!

Comment: I don't believe that's true, have you tested this?

Comment: Yes, every thing is automatic

Comment: That's very interesting to hear, because it directly contradicts Apple's documentation on the subject.

Comment: On iOS, iCloud documents are only downloaded on demand. For the file API that demand is created by calling `[NSFileManager startDownloadingUbiquitousItemAtURL:error:]`. Automatic downloading of documents is not normal or expected.